# Issue in pausing the posix thread for specific time interval in c

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have to call one method in seperate thread (i am using posix thread)which updates some value after every 5 second for which have written below code.

```
void *threadEntry(void *)
{
  while(1)
  {
    updateValue();//to update some values
    usleep(5000000);//pause for 5 second
   }
}
pthread_t thread1;
pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,threadEntry,NULL);
```

But this thread gets segmentation fault after 4-5 minutes .What can be reason?Is there any other way to pause the posix thread.(i am using linux)

Comment: could you add the backtrace of the crash to your question

Comment: Is the issue with the timing, or with the segfault ? Could you clarify this point ? Does for example removing the sleep and continuously calling updateValue lead to a segfault.

Comment: The crash is more likely to be in the updateValue() function that in the thread function you've shown.

Comment: The omitted parameter name is valid in C++; it is not valid in standard C.

Answer (score 1):

The right thing to do is to use nanosleep, because usleep and sleep might mess with SIGALARM, while nanosleep was specifically designed with threads in mind :

```
struct timespec mytimeout = {
    .tv_sec = 5,
    .tv_usec = 0,
};
struct timespec remaining;
nanosleep(&mytimeout, &remaining);
```

My original answer was to use a select trick, but let's stop promoting bad code

Back to the root of the problem, how do you know your segmentation fault come from the sleeping code ?
Did you get a core dump you could backtrace ?

Comment: Ough, long time that I didn't see that hack. No, don't do that, use `nanosleep`.

Comment: Also note that `nanosleep()` could return before the specified time with `errno` set to `EINTR`. If this is not okay, need to continue nanosleeping after setting `mytimeout = remaining` (in a loop).

Answer (score 1):

On POSIX systems (which linux is) `nanosleep` is the right thing for such a sleep:

```
int nanosleep(const struct timespec *req, struct timespec *rem);
```

where `req` is your request an `rem` is the time remaining to sleep if your thread was interrupted prematurely.